# Number of Involutions generating Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

How to show that strictly less than $n-1$ involutions (of which the transpositions are a special case) could not generate $S_{n}$ for $n > 3$?

I know that $n-1$ transpositions are sufficient, or that $S_n$ could be generated by the two elements $(1 ~ 2), (1 ~ 2 ~ \ldots ~ n)$, but what about less than $n-1$ involutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. For example, $S_{10}$ can be generated by the three involutions
(2,3), (3,5)(4,7)(6,9)(8,10), (1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8).

Of course for transpositions the answer is easy, as you need $n-1$ transpositions to be transitive on $n$ points.

Comment: In fact $S_n$ can be generated by three involutions for any $n$. Choose two involutions that generate the dihedral group of order $2n$ containing the $n$-cycle $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$, together with $(1,2)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. $S_3$ can be generated by two involution for example.

$<\{(1,2),(2,3)\}> =S_3$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wanted to exclude that case, which is somewhat special and I guess to be the only one. I edited the question for supposing that $n > 3$.

Comment: It is not the only, $S_4$ can be generated by $3$ involution.

Comment: Yes, sorry again, $S_n$ could always be generated by the $n-1$ involutions $(1 ~ 2), (1 ~ 3), \ldots, (1 ~ n)$, I meant less than $n-1$!